# Determine opened file handle mode on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, filehandle

The following code will give you the mode that a given handle is opened in (`<`, `>`, etc.):

```
use Fcntl qw(F_GETFL);
my $flags = fcntl($fh, F_GETFL, my $junk);
```

`$flags` is a number indicating the open mode (numbers defined by other macros provided by Fcntl). This, however, does not work on a Strawberry Perl installation. It fails with the following message:

```
Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro F_GETFL
```

How can this be achieved on a Windows installation of Perl?

The context is that I'm investigating a fix for [Data::Transform::ExplicitMetadata](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Transform::ExplicitMetadata). Its purpose is to make Perl structures serializable via JSON, and one thing that it needs to serialize is open file handles. See the current code [here](https://metacpan.org/source/BRUMMETT/Data-Transform-ExplicitMetadata-0.04/lib/Data/Transform/ExplicitMetadata.pm#L17).

Comment: Perhaps to step back and look *why* you need $flags, so answer might be in other direction.

Comment: Are you asking about the Perl handle or the underlying system handle?

Comment: @mpapec I added the context to the question.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not really sure. See my edit for the context. I'd like to be able to tell if a file was opened with '<', '>', '<<', etc.

Comment: I take that to mean "anything I can grab since the feature is going to be insanely fragile no matter what I do". As such, you could grab the mode Perl has for it. You can see it in `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump *STDOUT{IO}'`. You should be able to grab it using B::.

Comment: (I suggest you do like Storable and leave globs and file handles unsupported. It simply makes no sense. They're not data, so they can't be meaningfully serialized.)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I'll look into. It's not my module, and the module specifically claims support for stuff that's not normally serializable, so I don't want to submit an issue saying to remove functionality. I just want this fixed because it's a dependency for Devel::hdb, which I happen to love.

Comment: @ikegami: almost had it: https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=122975&results=d4384595fd8d2232b24500da4c3ac8d2